# How to keep Firestore and Firebase Storage in sync

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on my first site built with firebase, and a little intimidated by the "serverless" architecture. I'm used to doing a lot of backend verification, and having the client decide too many things is making me want to be very defensive.

One such example is this. Users can submit posts. Posts can contain files. Each of those in isolation is manageable

```
firestore().collection('posts').add({
  title: "my new post",
  author: "my username",
  uploaded: new Date(),
  location: "a10b308cd" // some location in firebase storage
});
```

I can use firestore rules to make sure the author matches the authenticated user, and stuff like that.

Likewise I can upload a file:

```
const uuid = new UUID();
const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(uuid);
ref.put(file)
```

But it's very confusing to me how I should link these two together. The solution seems to be that the client comes up with a UUID for the storage location (namespaced to the user even) - and uses that in both the `firestore.add()` and the `ref.put()` calls.

There just doesn't seem a ton I can do to validate this behavior is correct though. I'm not used to having to trust clients to place files in the right places in my backend. It's unlikely there's going to be lots of malicious clients making messed up links, but it's still very unsettling to me.

Not even a malicious scenario, but if my Storage didn't submit (EG because of internet issues or incorrect file upload against Storage rules) and the client still tried to make a document addition, I'd have no way in `firestore.rules` to if they'res a file where they are linking.

I have a regex to determine if the uuid looks like a uuid, but clients could still set it to "deadbeef1010101010" and I'm powerless to stop it! A randomly generated backend UUID is much preferable than relying on clients - even though it shouldn't matter when they're namespaced.

Am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: Yup, it's hard.  Security rules can't span products, so you'd need some backend code that manages all the access to make sure that all your requirements are met.  What you're trying to do is possible, it's just going to require a non-trivial amount of work to stitch together.  Cloud Functions triggers can help.

Comment: Ahh thanks for at least validating my struggle :)

I was curious if Cloud Functions would be the solution, I imagine it shouldn't be too difficult to put a verification on doc submissions that they link to a valid storage location. Just wasn't sure if it was standard practice